# Unable to show icon bind with span html tag

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a string message where I want to show icon along with string message in asp.net with c#. Once page loaded it is showing normal string not an icon

```
  public string InfoMessage;
  InfoMessage = "Please choose at least one image type from the settings panel. You can configure this gadget by pressing the <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-inline ui-icon-wrench'></span>icon at the top of this gadget.";
```

I want wrench icon visible but it is showing

Comment: this is a good first question but we could benefit from seeing the HTML and CSS as well in order to help.

Comment: is the css with icon definitions loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Webforms App. try this one:

html code:

```
<span id="webcontent" runat="server">
 </span>
```

Code behind:

```
  webcontent.InnerHtml = InfoMessage;
```

For ASP.NET MVC App Use below:

Controller:

```
  string InfoMessage;
        InfoMessage = "Please choose at least one image type from the settings panel. You can configure this gadget by pressing the <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-inline ui-icon-wrench'></span>icon at the top of this gadget.";
        ViewBag.Message = InfoMessage;
```

View:

```
<span>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</span>
```